# PHP simple extract from array

Tags: php, arrays

I need a simple way to extract values from an array.
I just can't get it to work.

This is the array from the database with `<pre>`:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Title2
    )
)
```

I can't get the titles to echo :-(

M.

-EDIT-

This did the trick for me:

```
foreach($arrays as $array)
{
  echo $array['title'];
}
```

Comment: post your code here so we can see what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arrays as $array)
{
      echo $array['title'];
}
```

Comment: Jezus! That simple uh. Thnx.

Comment: @Interactive or you can directly access the elements: `echo $arrays[0]['title'];`

Comment: That works for small number of arrays . But for large data its useless. Always use this method. Its simple and powerful.

Comment: @user3411648 I will but the answer was given so quickly that I have to wait 15 min. :-)

Comment: If the array is big and you want all of them means you have to wait . Or you can directly give the index number. It depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array like:

```
 foreach($array as $arr)
 {
      echo $arr['title'];
 }
```

Or to access one item, use:

```
 echo $array[0]['title'];
 echo $array[1]['title'];
```